# PHP Regex to extract parameters within double square brackets (Modx Tags)

Tags: php, regex, modx

I'm trying to write a regex to extract the value of a particular parameter from an array of content in a modx database. the format of the tags is:

```
[[!video? &path=`_path_to_video` &width=`123` &height=`123` &someotherparm=`bar`]]
```

I am trying to get the content of the &path parameter using this regex:

```
preg_match_all('/\[\[path=`(.*?)`\]\]/', $content, $tags, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER) ;
```

but without luck - it just returns empty arrays when I dump the $tags variable.

something wrong with my regex?

Comment: There is no `[[path=` in your string.

Comment: You are looking for `&path`. Right?

Comment: The `parameter's` would be the ones starting with `&`

Comment: ok - no &path=  so there's 1 error I need to figure out the regex for anything before path

Comment: parameters do start with & but sometimes a text editor will encode them to &amp; - so I can't guarantee that "path" will start with a & occasionally the tag is also written [[!video?path=`` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern doesn't match the tag format:

```
preg_match_all('/&path=`([^`]+)`/', $content, $tags, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

- Match `&path=` then backtick, then
- Match anything that is not a backtick up until another backtick and capture it

If you really need to match the existence of `[[` and closing `]]` then:

```
preg_match_all('/\[\[.*&path=`([^`]+)`.*\]\]/', $content, $tags, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Comment: You forgot *within double square brackets* part.

Comment: Yes, the other answer covers that if it's needed.

Comment: I will retract my down-vote if your solution was an answer to this question.

Comment: Maybe not worth an upvote, but not worth a downvote either.

Comment: actually your first example is a much more to the point.  though I may at some point have to find all the tags [[!whatever? ]] and extract all the parameters as an array...

Comment: actually - yes I do need to find the instances with double quotes & the path param.  I actually should be stripping the tag from the content once I have the value of the video path!

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
'/\[\[.*?&path=`([^`]+?)`.*?\]\]/'
```

Comment: You need some fixes. 1) Replace `.*?` with `[^]]*?`. 2) Remove lazy quantifier on `[^\`]+?`